# Retorno de Json

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net, json

Ainda não entendo o funcionamento de JSON, mas aqui eu tenho um código do Controller que retorna um JSON e quero saber como exibo estes dados na tela.

```
public ActionResult ShowPlaylists()
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Session["token"].ToString()))
        return View("Index");

    var access_token = Session["token"].ToString();

    SpotifyService spotifyService = new SpotifyService();

    SpotifyUser spotifyUser = spotifyService.GetUserProfile(access_token);

    Playlists playlists = spotifyService.GetPlaylists(spotifyUser.UserId, access_token);

    return Json(playlists);
}
```

Comment: Json serve para tudo, menos para isso que você quer: exibir em tela.

Comment: e qual alternativa eu teria pra mostrar os dados do Json?

Comment: A ideia seria você alimentar algum elemento da tela com o Json. Por exemplo, um componente JS, ou ainda popular um elemento HTML usando os dados do JSON. Por exemplo: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18484762/populating-drop-down-with-json-object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você está misturando as funções no controller, para se usar o json num método você deve usar JsonResult como identificador do tipo de retorno. Em asp.net mvc há duas formas de fazer uma chamada Ajax e com isso ter um registro ou uma lista de registros em json, segue dois exemplos que faz chamada no mesmo controller para que tenha um melhor entendimento:

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<JsonResult> JsonX()
{
    var frente = (from d in db.Imagem
                  orderby d.IdImagem
                  select new
                  {
                      d.IdImagem,
                      d.EnderecoImagem,
                      d.DescricaoLegenda,
                      d.CorFundoLegenda,
                      d.Descricao,
                      d.Largura,
                      d.Altura,
                      d.DescricaoAlternativa,
                  });
    return Json(await frente.ToListAsync());
}
```

Opção 1 de chamada do Ajax - eu utilizo em situações que desejo criar elementos em html dinamicamente, montar uma tabela, por exemplo, e mostrar ao usuário:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">            
    $.ajax({
        url: "/ControllerX/JsonX",
        type: "POST",
        ifModified: true,
        cache: true,
        async: true,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.length > 0) {
                var linha = "";
                for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    linha += data[i] + "<br>";
                }
         }
    });
 </script>
```

Opção 2 de chamada do Ajax - utilizo mais em situações que não quero reflesh na página toda, exemplo, adicionar um item num carrinho em uma loja virtual. Enfim, dependendo da forma que fizer pode usar as duas formas para a mesma finalidade:

```
 <form class="form-inline" method="post" action="/ControllerX/JsonX" data-ajax="true" 
        data-ajax-failure="FalhaAjax" data-ajax-success="SucessoAjax">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <input class="input-sm form-control" type="submit" />
            </div>
        </div>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">         
   function SucessoAjax(data) {
        if (data.length > 0) {
                var linha = "";
                for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    linha += data[i] + "<br>";
                }
         }
   }
   function FalhaAjax(data) {
        alert("erro");
   }
</script>
```

Comment: Obrigado @Cleve irei testar aqui no Projeto.